# iView link a menu-item with content

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, single-page-application, vue-component

I'm developing an administrator console for my Android game. It's a single page web application. I'm using Vue.js and iView. So the main page contains a iView side navigation bar, it contains `menu-items`, and I'm trying to link each `menu-item` with a different component to be displayed on the screen, but `@click` and `@select` and `@change` doesn't trigger the function that updates the displayed component. Here is the code:

```
            <Sider hide-trigger :style="{background: '#fff'}">
                <Menu  v-bind:active-name="currentActiveBranch" theme="light" width="auto" v-bind:open-names="[currentActiveSection]" accordion>
                    <Submenu v-for="section in sections" :key="section.title" v-bind:name="section.title">
                        <template slot="title">
                            <Icon v-bind:type="section.icon"></Icon>
                            {{ section.title }}
                        </template>
                        <menu-item v-for="branch in section.branches" :key="branch" v-bind:name="branch">{{ branch }}</menu-item>
                    </Submenu>
                </Menu>
            </Sider>
```

So I want the displayed component to be changed whenever the `menu-item` selected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After searching the solution was using `@click.native="function_name"`.
For more information, check this link:
https://github.com/iview/iview/issues/2412